# Environment Variable for CircleCI

Tags: circleci

What does this variable mean in CircleCI

> CIRCLE_SHA1
>
> The SHA1 of the commit being tested.

How can i set the value for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the SHA1 hash of the commit as created by Git. You can see examples of these hashes for each commit when you run `git log`.

You don't set the value for this. It's created by CircleCI to show you the commit that CircleCI is currently building.